# How do you join two arrays in Swift combing and preserving the order of each array? (Interleaving arrays in swift)

Tags: iphone, arrays, sorting, swift

I have two arrays and I need to preserve the order

```
let a = ["Icon1", "Icon2", "Icon3",]
let b = ["icon1.png", "icon2.png", "icon3.png",]
```

If I combine the two I get

```
let c = a + b
// [Icon1, Icon2, Icon3, icon1.png, icon2.png, icon3.png]
```

How do I get the result below?

```
[Icon1, icon1.png, Icon2, icon2.png, Icon3, icon3.png]
```

Comment: Hmm... That + operator should not work like that. It should append the values from the second array onto the first array.

Comment: as I stated in my last comment before deleting my answer. The misleading title lead me to read the question the other way around which is why I deleted my answer.

Comment: Ok, no worries, Michael understood the question and answered. Agree with Michael, I'm obviously new, because I didn't know what interleaving is, its now "misleading?" :)

Comment: My excuse is it's currently 2am and my brain isn't working right. :-P

Comment: :) Thank you both for fighting **so** hard to answer this. I do actually appreciate it!

Comment: @Fogmeister you are correct that concat is supposed to be += but it will work the way I've written it here too for some reason : http://d.pr/i/1aOtl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE 12/16/2015: Not sure why I didn't recognize that flatMap was a good candidate here. Perhaps it wasn't in the core library at the time? Anyway the map/reduce can be replaced with one call to flatMap. Also Zip2 has been renamed. The new solution is

```
let c = Zip2Sequence(a,b).flatMap{[$0, $1]}
```

And if you run this in the swift repl environment:

```
> let c = Zip2Sequence(a,b).flatMap{[$0, $1]}
c: [String] = 6 values {
  [0] = "Icon1"
  [1] = "icon1.png"
  [2] = "Icon2"
  [3] = "icon2.png"
  [4] = "Icon3"
  [5] = "icon3.png"
}
```

Original answer below:

Here's one way I whipped together for fun

```
let c = map(Zip2(a,b), { t in
  [t.0, t.1]
})

let d = c.reduce([], +)
```

or inlining

```
let c = map(Zip2(a,b), { t in
  [t.0, t.1]
}).reduce([], +)
```

The zipping seems unnecessary. I imagine there's a better way of doing that. But basically, I'm zipping them together, then converting each tuple into an array, and then flattening the array of arrays.

Finally, a little shorter:

```
let c = map(Zip2(a,b)){ [$0.0, $0.1] }.reduce([], +)
```

Comment: Boom. awesome. Really appreciate the super short option too. If you find something better than the zip I'd be interested to know. It does answer the question though. Again, thanks!

Comment: I edited and removed the down vote (and then edited back). :-)

Comment: Cool, glad we patched it up. I've been a member 3 years, but just recently started trying to learn the ropes and interact more. Don't want to start a flame war with an experience member. :-)

Comment: @Aubrey the only idea I've had since writing this is to write my own structure, let's call it `Mesh2` which like `Zip2` is a `SequenceType`. The difference being that the generated sequence of `Mesh2` would contain "doubleton" lists rather than tuples. That would remove the need for the `map`. It would then look something like `let c = reduce(Mesh2(a,b), [], +)`. So that line of code would be shorter but you'd have the whole `Mesh2` implementation which probably isn't that useful other than this particular use case.

Comment: Or you could take it one step further and create a `Mesh` structure that is a `SequenceType` which returns the elements just as you wish. Then you'd still have to convert the resulting SequenceType into an array (assuming that's the resulting type you need).

Answer (score 0):

If both arrays are related to each other and both have the same size you just have append one at a time in a single loop:

```
let a = ["Icon1", "Icon2", "Icon3"]
let b = ["icon1.png", "icon2.png", "icon3.png"]
var result:[String] = []
for index in 0..<a.count {
    result.append(a[index])
    result.append(b[index])
}
println(result)    // "[Icon1, icon1.png, Icon2, icon2.png, Icon3, icon3.png]"
```

and just for the fun this is how it would look like as a function:

```
func interleaveArrays<T>(array1:[T], _ array2:[T]) -> Array<T> {
    var result:[T] = []
    for index in 0..<array1.count {
        result.append(array1[index])
        result.append(array2[index])
    }
    return result
}

interleaveArrays(a, b)    // ["Icon1", "icon1.png", "Icon2", "icon2.png", "Icon3", "icon3.png"]
```

Answer (score -1):

May be it can help you.

```
let aPlusB = ["Icon1" : "icon1.png" , "Icon2" : "icon2.png" , "Icon3" : "icon3.png"]

    for (aPlusBcode, aplusBName) in aPlusB {

        println("\(aPlusBcode),\(aplusBName)")
 }
```

Comment: Actually, I was also not sure, but there may be something like that helps you. Yeah, it is dictionary!

Comment: Gotcha, FYI dictionaries do not preserve order, so that would not work.